# Запрос на выборку из 2-х таблиц SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Есть две таблицы вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как их можно объединить, чтобы бы получился такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Где в `Таблице 1` и `2` `Столбец 1` одинаковый.

Во `2-м столбце` `таблицы 2` могут некоторые даты отсутствовать (`столбец 2` это даты всего месяца).

В `3-ю таблицу` нужно добавить `столбец 3` из `таблицы 1` и `2`.

Пробовал делать так, но данные показывает не верные:

```
SELECT Tab1.OPS, Tab1.DateSaldo, Tab1.Saldo, Tab2.SaldoEisk FROM db_1c as Tab1 OUTER APPLY (SELECT top 1 * from db_eisk as Tab2 Where Tab2.OPSeisk = Tab1.OPS) as Tab2 ORDER BY Tab1.OPS
```

Comment: повеселило "во втором столбце таблицы 2 могут некоторые даты отсутствовать". Попробуйте JOIN по первому столбцу обеих таблиц (как японял, он вам должен подойти)

Comment: если хотите более развернутый ответ, добавьте смысловой нагрузки на таблицы....а то стоблец1, столбец2 ... не понятные данные (кроме типов ничего не понятно). Не понятно откудого взялось в 3й таблицу 13 строка последний столбец. Ведь у табл 2 всего 10 строк

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц, Так тоже не те данные SELECT t1.OPS, t1.Date, t1.Saldo, t2.SaldoE FROM db_1c t1 INNER JOIN db_eisk t2 ON t1.OPS = t2.OPSe

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц, по id тоже не получится, так как Id не совпадают со значением в столбце 1

Comment: `select t1.f1, t1.f2, t1.f3, t2.f3 from t1 left join t2 on t1.f1 = t2.f1 and t1.f2 = t2.f2`?

Comment: хорошо...по `id` не получится. Тогда скажите признак, по которому может получится...иначе без смысловой нагрузки не понятно

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц, вот мне нужно чтобы в 3 третьей таблице, отображались данные 3 столбца 1 и 2 таблицы, где мы производим проверку на равенство 1 столбца 1 и 2 таблицы. Если равны, то в 3 таблицу записываем значение из 1 и 2 таблицы, где столбец 3.

Comment: Откуда тогда появляются записи 11, 12, 13 ? ... `проверку на равенство 1 столбца 1 и 2 таблицы` - не подходит под это условие

Comment: Виталий Шебаниц, это пример их может и не быть, тогда там должно быть пусто

Comment: Ок, то что я вижу: 1) вы используете `FULL OUTER JOIN` по `id`. Проходитесь потом по выбранным данным на `c#` если находите `null`, то добавляете существующую (справа или слева) в зависимости от того, где `null`. 2) Добавляете в вопрос дамп таблиц с минимальными данными, а то так и не понятно и затестить нельзя

Comment: Создайте fiddle с данными (фотографии - это сакс) и покажите ответ строго для этих данных.

Comment: [например тут](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/40986/1/0

Comment: @Akina, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/40986/1/0

Comment: ну вот вы получили какие-то данные....вам так подходит, или нужно по другому?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, они не правильные. Например вот первая строка результата. Первые три столбца берутся из таблицы dbEisk, 4 столбец надо чтобы был пустой, так как в таблице db1c нет данных за 29.09.2019

Comment: Блин, читайте ВСЁ сообщение, а не первые три слова! Повторяю: *и покажите ответ **строго для этих данных***. И показывать фотографии с одним наполнением, а делать fiddle с другим - тоже можно исключительно с целью запутать отвечающих.

Comment: *4 столбец надо чтобы был пустой, так как в таблице db1c нет данных за 29.09.2019* Извольте следить за своими же словами. Цитирую: *Где в Таблице 1 и 2 Столбец 1 одинаковый*. А Вы какой столбец приравняли в тексте своего запроса??? И где вообще в запросе хоть что-то с датой? Кстати, если "Столбец 1" в тексте вопроса - это `[ops]` и `[opsEisk]` в созданном fiddle - то огорчу. Значения этих полей в fiddle не уникальны, так что для связи они в принципе непригодны.